# Want my WCF service to run under the administrator account

Tags: wcf, impersonation

How can I configure my WCF service to run under the administrator account? (this is not for production, just testing).

Is it simply a web.config tweak?

IIS 7 hosted WCF service.

Comment: How are you hosting your service?

Answer (score 2):

If you are hosting it as an ASP.NET service, you should run IIS process as the administrator account. If you are hosting it under a Windows service, you should configure it to run as an administrator.

Comment: Of course, it goes without saying that running the IIS process under an administrator account is an abysmally bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

under IIS 7 make sure the service runs under an application pool configured to run under the desired user.